# Udev rule to automatically disable touchpad when a USB mouse is connected

Tags: udev

I am pretty new to `udev` and  wanted to write a rule that upon connecting an usb mouse disables my touchpad.

This is what I have come up with(mostly by ear):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="USB_Mouse", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/nikitautiu/.Xauthority", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0", RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=1"
```

Nonetheless it doesn't trigger the desired effect. The command seems to be fine though the rule does not trigger when connecting my usb mouse.

Comment: Yes it does, I am 100% sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't grasp why your rule is so complex? Especially this section

```
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="USB_Mouse",\
ENV{DISPLAY}=":0",\
ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/nikitautiu/.Xauthority",\   
ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0"
```

In the first line you match the environment variable `ID_MODEL` which is only seen by `udev` against `USB_Mouse`. In the following three lines you assign values to environment variables. Again only seen by `udev` and the executed command `synclient` if the rule is applied.

I'm pretty sure that this rule is never applied (You can check this by parsing `udev`'s log file.) since it is likely that there is no variable `ID_MODEL` with content `USB_Mouse` accessible unless you set `ID_MODEL` in the `udev` environment previously.

I suggest that you match against the Action, the vendor-ID and the product-ID of your mouse, which will suffice in most cases. Then your rule looks like

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<idVendor>", ATTRS{idProduct}=="<idProduct>", RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=1"
```

You can get `<idVendor>` and the `<idProduct>` by parsing the output of

```
lsusb -v
```

I don't remember if the given hex-values are allowed in the classical form `0xffff`. I always take only the part behind `0x` in my rules.

Comment: Well it works, but this is `vendor` or `product` dependant. Isn't there any attr or env varaible to identify a usb mouse by? **PS:** It's hex by default, no need for `0x`

Comment: A more generic approach would be to match against `ACTION=="add", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03", ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"`. These are specific characteristics for a usb mouse. For further information see `lsusb -v` and http://www.usb.org/developers/defined_class.

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer doesn't work on my system here is a `udev` rule that works with `gnome/gdm v. 3.16.2` and `udev/systemd v. 226`:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03", \
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority", \
ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/usr/bin/xinput --enable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'", \
RUN+="/usr/bin/xinput --disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'"
```

`ENV{REMOVE_CMD}` is the command used when the device is removed.
`SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` is the name of the touchpad device as reported by `xinput`.
The `UID` used in `ENV{XAUTHORITY}` (e.g. `1000` in my rule) has to match your user `ID`.
Note the backslashes at end of lines are needed, as otherwise `udev` rules cannot span over multiple lines. If you prefer in one line:

```
 ACTION=="add", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03", ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/usr/bin/xinput --enable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'", RUN+="/usr/bin/xinput --disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'"
```

Comment: How would you do that with Xauthority for KDE? There is no such file. All I can see is that `echo $XAUTHORITY` gives `/tmp/xauth-1000-_0`. Maybe just ignore this variable? Why did you need that in the first place? Thanks

Comment: @DrBeco - I'm not on linux anymore but as far as I remember on KDE the file is  `/home/username/.Xauthority` i.e. exactly what the OP used. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Given another answer that works on KDE (plasma, sddm).

I added the rule filename `/etc/udev/rules.d/61-touchpadoff.rules` with the following content:

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="touchpadoff_end"

KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="input", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/usr/bin/xinput --enable 'Elan TouchPad'", RUN+="/usr/bin/xinput --disable 'Elan TouchPad'"

LABEL="touchpadoff_end"
```

You need to thange the name of your touchpad hardware. To see it issue a command `% xinput --list`

I hope this helps you KDE-heads.